# Plot a simple coordinate systems with vectors

Tags: r, plot

How could I create a simple plot of a coordinate system within two vectors in R? It should look like the following plot.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `arrows` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Empty plot
plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3), asp = 1,
     ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE)

# Axes
arrows(x0 = -3, y0 = 0, x1 = 3, y1 = 0, length = 0.1, code = 3)
arrows(x0 = 0, y0 = -3, x1 = 0, y1 = 3, length = 0.1, code = 3)

# Vectors
# v1
arrows(0, 0, 2.5, 1, length = 0.1, col = "lightblue", lwd = 2)
# v2
arrows(0, 0, 1, 2, length = 0.1, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
# v3
arrows(1, 2, 2.5, 1, length = 0.1, col = "red", lwd = 2)

# Text
text(x = mean(c(0, 2.5)), y = mean(c(0, 1)), labels = "v1", pos = 1)
text(0.5, 1, "v2", pos = 3)
text(1.75, 1.5, "v3", pos = 4)
```